# MySql - Grouping table items in new table

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have a table of items, with unique ids, and a table of bundles, which is a number of items together. Each bundle has a unique id also. To create the bundles, do I use a table that duplicates an item for each bundle it is in and gives it a bundle id which is joined to the bundles table? That seems inefficient.

Comment: You should give more information in your question, details about your table, what you have tested, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the exact kind of your relationship:

- Every item belongs to only one bundle: Add a field to the item table, that stores the bundle ID. Consider using foreign keys to assure consistency
- An item can belong to more than one bundle: Use a join table, that has a column for bundle id and one for item id: Use at least a unique key to make sure, every relation is stored only once. Consider using foreign keys to assure consitency.